# Chrome extensions bug?

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10, multiple-monitors, google-chrome-extensions

I have encountered a strange bug while using my Google Chrome extension. Whenever I try to use an extension that shows an additional pop-up/window/dropdown menu (basically any extra content in a separate area) it simply doesn't show anything if **the browser window is on my secondary monitor**.

For example, I have the todoist extension. If I click it while the browser is opened on my main monitor it works fine and shows my tasks. If I drag that window on my second monitor (regardles the window size, it can be maximized, fullscreen, etc...) and click the todoist icon, the icon changes it's state to a pressed or selected state but doesn't show the tasks list...

The same happens with all extensions (window resizer, color picker, todoist, lastpass, etc...) BUT for example for color picker I press the icon sometimes I see part of the context menu, like it fails to render the whole thing:

[image]

Still, this only happens on my secondary monitor.

Just a note, as it might be related: the main monitor is plugged into the dedicated GPU while the secondary monitor into the integrated GPU.

Comment: You should report the bug to Chrome and verify an earlier version or newer  version of Chrome does or does not have this problem.

Comment: @Ramhound Where is the place to report Chrome bugs?

Comment: [Report a problem or send feedback on Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95315?hl=en)

Comment: I was just about to post the same thing. I reinstalled Chrome the other day, clearing the AppData inbetween and it fixed it until I restarted, then the problem came back.

Comment: I have three monitors, all plugged into dedicated GPUs (I have two) and it only ever shows on monitor 1 (which is the central one for me). Have you installed a secondary installation of Chrome at all (like Chrome Canary?) because I suspect it seems to have started around the same time I did that. Not sure though.

Comment: *Booted up today and the issue was fixed!* They do listen to those bug reports then :) Version is 50.0.2661.75 just for reference.

Comment: @slugmandrew Yay, thanks for pointing that out. I have updated from 49 to 50 and now it's working (it wasn't working in 49)

Answer (score 0):

The version in the Google Chrome store does not work. You have to install the version from the Todoist website. That worked immediately.

Comment: For me it does work, it was a bug in Chrome versions lower than 49.